# How to update counter without sending request to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I m building a website where i need to update project counter whenever its updated in DB. when ever any user add a new project, the project counter should automatically update in browser, but i don't want to send ajax request to server again and again to get count from DB and then update counter in web browser.

I want something similar "how facebook notification updated" automatically without refreshing page or sending any ajax request, i know there are using some PUSH technology but i not sure how it works.

It will be very great if someone provide some Example code to achieve this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using SignalR?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

http://signalr.net/

Here is the sample code based on a quick POC after reading some SO replies and above articles. Hope it helps.

- Create a new empty ASP.NET web application project
- Add the SignalR package via NuGet
- Add a UserCounter.cs with following code. Just need to inherit the class from Hub base class.

  ```
  using SignalR.Hubs;
  public class UserCounter : Hub { }
  ```
- Add a Default.aspx with following code:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div>
              Number of users currently online - <b><span id="noOfUsers">0</span> users</b>
              <br />
              <a target="_blank" href="UpdateNoOfUsers.aspx">Change number of users</a>
          </div>
      </form>
      </body>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          var usc = $.connection.userCounter;

          usc.noOfUsersUpdated = function (message) {
              $('#noOfUsers').text(message);
          };

          $.connection.hub.start();
      });
  </script>

  </html>
  ```
- Add a UpdateNoOfUsers.aspx with following code:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  </head>
      <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
              <div>
                  No. of users: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
              </div>
          </form>
      </body>
      </html>
  ```
- Add an event-handler for button-click for button in UpdateNoOfUsers.aspx

  ```
  using SignalR;
  using SignalR.Infrastructure;
  using SignalR.Hosting.AspNet;

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
      dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<UserCounter>();
      clients.noOfUsersUpdated(TextBox1.Text);
  }
  ```
- Run the application after setting "Default.aspx" as the start up page
- Click on the "Change number of users" link to open a new browser window
- Enter a number in text-box and click on the button to see the value change in base window! Open this page in some other browser and see the same behaviour!